# Git diff command doesn't work with jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, centos7

I have a Jenkins pipeline with a bash script to get the difference of repository TAGs. Below git diff command doesn't work with jenkins pipeline. This jenkins is installed on CentOS 7. The same script works fine with ubuntu 22.04. Note: when the script run manually on CentOS it runs perfectly. Issue occur when it run with jenkins.

git diff ${release-TAG} --name-only --diff-filter=d > path/changefile

I've change the permissions and changed the owner. In the same script i have run git branch in the same directory this also works fine. only the git diff command doesn't work.

Comment: How does it not work? Does it show wrong information? Does it do nothing? Does it throw an error?

Comment: Don't use jenkins then

Comment: @TeemuRisikko only this line of script doesn't execute. no error thrown.

Comment: Do you do a full-history clone of the repo on Jenkins, or is it a shallow (single commit) clone? In the latter case you will get no diffs.